# Recover Service Account on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud

I have deleted a Service Account by mistake and I have been reading this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) but I can't find any option to recover it.

Is it possible to recover a deleted account?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) command line tool, though its in a `beta` at the moment, it still works perfectly and got me out of a sticky situation

`gcloud beta app repair --project <your project id>`

This will restore all the default service accounts. [docs here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair) They were quite hard for me to find, so I hope this answer helps others.

Comment: This got me out of a jam and seemed to work just fine as of this afternoon. Do you have any idea when it will be out of beta?